# Set Radio Group to Transparent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, radio-button

I'm making a Cocoa application, and by default, I want to have a radio group be transparent at the start of the application. I've read the apple documentation, and found that `- (void)setTransparent:(BOOL)flag` will make a button transparent, and I tried to apply this to my radio group using this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [_extraChannelTypeInput setTransparent:YES];
}
```

but it didn't work, because it's not declared for a matrix (which makes sense, but it was worth a try). I was wondering if there was any way to make a radio group transparent.

**Edit**
I've looked into it more, and each individual radio can be made transparent, however, even when I used the button, this didn't work.
Also, the link to the page about transparency is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe setting up of the alpha value should make it transparent.

```
An outlet for radio group
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSMatrix *myMatrix;
```

Then you can set the alpha value for the my matrix.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    
    self.myMatrix.alphaValue = 0.0f; //or 0.5f
}
```